# Unwanted tiling effect in HTML5 canvas when zooming

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using html5 canvas to manipulate individual pixels. The canvas is zoomable and draggable, and each pixel is a rectangle, basically I do the following:

```
 pixels.forEach(p => {
     context.fillStyle = p.color;
     context.fillRect(toScreenX(p.x), toScreenY(p.y), 1*scale, 1*scale);
 });
```

where `toScreenX` and `toScreenY` determine the position of the rectangle based on the position of the pixel and the actual scale and offset.

When the zoom scale is 1, everything is okay as shown on picture below:

[image: no zooming]

However, when I start to zoom in, thin white lines start to appear between pixels, and the picture gets distorted as shown in the two figure below:
[image]

Here's a short video about the effect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pff6E.jpg
I also tried to use `context.putImageData` instead of `fillRect` but for individual pixels, it gets terribly slow.

Comment: Using drawImage is not an option for you?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda no, I can't use drawImage, I want pixel-level manipulation, something similar to https://pixelcanvas.io/

Comment: You need to round your coordinates. However you might get better perfs by using an ImageData directly and rescale it on your context.